# Error in Deployment of WPF application With Target Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, frameworks, mahapps.metro

I have getting Error in Deployment of WPF application With Target Framework 4.0 on some Client Machine and Application got crash.

I'm also using MahApps.Metro

> ```
> Detail Error comes:
> Problem signature:
> Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
> Problem Signature 01: digitalesigner.exe
> Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.15
> Problem Signature 03: 56700a86
> Problem Signature 04: PresentationFramework
> Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
> Problem Signature 06: 4ba1f8db
> Problem Signature 07: 7c4
> Problem Signature 08: 1f
> Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileLoadException
> OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
> Locale ID:    1033
> Additional Information 1: 0a9e
> Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
> Additional Information 3: 0a9e
> Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
> C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
> ```

Comment: Can you try uninstalling MahApps.Metro with nuget manager, and re-installing? I had some problems when I moved from NET 4.5 to 4.0 and uninstall/reinstall worked for me.